# Save each row of df to separate xml

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to iterate through each row of an excel file, and save the output for each row to it's separate .xml file. However, when I run the code, instead of having each row in a separate .xml file, I have all rows being saved to each generated .xml files. Obviously, I'm having confusion about iteration, and would gladly appreciate any help. Here's my current code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_excel ('C:/Users/Downloads/Book1.xlsx')

df['name'] = df['name'].map(str)
df.set_index('name',inplace=True)

for name, data in df.iterrows():
    (df.to_xml('D:/Test/' + name + '.xml' , attr_cols=["disabled", "error-if-not-time", "interval-type", "name" , "type" , "verbose"], 
                 row_name = "assesslet"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change `df` in loop to `data` then convert `data` to one row DataFrame since there is no `Series.to_xml()`

```py
for name, data in df.iterrows():
    (data.to_frame().T.to_xml('D:/Test/' + name + '.xml' , attr_cols=["disabled", "error-if-not-time", "interval-type", "name" , "type" , "verbose"], 
                 row_name = "assesslet"))
```

Comment: Hi Ynjxsjmh, thank you for your time. I think I understand what you're doing - I did get an error, though, that says 'no valid column, name'. I don't really know why I'm getting this error because my df does have a name column, and was working before w/ name

Comment: @george12 The error occurs at `data.to_frame().T.to_xml()` this row?

Comment: @george12 Does `print(data.to_frame().T.columns)` has `name`?

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh is it possible that you do transpose and column names are gone? It might be reason with op's reason for getting error. Not sure though.

Comment: @mmustafaicer It couldn't, `data` is a row in dataframe and `.to_frame().T` is to convert it to one row dataframe as in original dataframe.

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh, when I run **print(data.to_frame().T.columns)**, I actually do not see the index **name**. Maybe, I am making a mistake. It prints out : `Index(['Runnable', 'Rate\n(ms)', 'disabled', 'verbose', 'hash-uptodate',
       'error-if-not-time', 'interval-type', 'type'],
      dtype='object')`

Comment: @george12 Problem is you don't have `name` column, what's the output of `df.columns` at the same time?

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh output is `Index(['Runnable', 'Rate\n(ms)', 'disabled', 'verbose', 'hash-uptodate',
       'error-if-not-time', 'interval-type', 'type'],
      dtype='object')`

Comment: @george12 It's interesting that this also doesn't contain `name` column but you don't get an error before. But I found you have set `name` column has index before.

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh when I ran the other posters code below, I also got errors for my other column, for example , it says **no valid column, error-if-not-time** or **disabled**.  It's definitely weird, I couldn't say why it's doing that

Comment: @george12 If you mean `pd.DataFrame(data)`, it actually doesn't meet your need. Your problem here is you set the `name` column as index before `df.set_index('name',inplace=True)`, so there is no `name` column. You should remove it in `attr_cols`.

Answer (score 0):

try:

```py
for name, data in df.iterrows():
    pd.DataFrame(data).to_xml(('D:/Test/' + name + '.xml') , attr_cols=["disabled", "error-if-not-time", "interval-type", "name" , "type" , "verbose"], 
                 row_name = "assesslet")
```

[`to_xml()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_xml.html) is DataFrame specific. But each time you iterate, you end up with Pandas Series. That is why I used `pd.DataFrame()`. You can also use `to_frame()` just like mentioned above. Also first argument, encapsulate it with parenthesis since it is a string concatenation.